# Complex roots problem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've got a complex equation with 4 roots that I am solving. In my calculations it seems like I am going through hell and back to find these roots (and I'm not even sure I am doing it right) but if I let a computer calculate it, it just seems like it finds the form and then multiplies by $i$ and negative $i$. Have a look: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288*sqrt%283%29%29%2F%28z%5E4%2B8%29%3Di](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288*sqrt%283%29%29/%28z%5E4%2b8%29=i)

Here's me going bald: [image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Click the "Approximate Forms" button and think about what the numbers could be !

Comment: My calculations appear wrong :( Do you see what is wrong with them?

Comment: I cannot see them since I am blind. Sorry for that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing things:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{8\sqrt 3}{z^4 + 8} &= i \implies\\
z^4 + 8 &= \frac{8\sqrt 3}{i} = -i\,8\sqrt 3\\
z^4 &= -8-i8\sqrt{3} 
\\&= 
16\left(\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) +i\,\sin \left(\frac{4\pi}{3} \right)  \right)
\\&= 
16\left(\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3} + 2 \pi\right) +i\,\sin \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi \right)  \right)
\\&= 
16\left(\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3} + 4 \pi\right) +i\,\sin \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}+4\pi \right)  \right)
\\&= 
16\left(\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3} + 6 \pi\right) +i\,\sin \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}+6\pi \right)  \right)
\end{align*}
$$
Taking $\sqrt[4]{16}$ and dividing each of these angles by $4$ gives you all $4$ of the $4^{th}$ roots, which are
$$
\begin{align*}
z= 
& 2\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) +i\,\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3} \right)  \right),
\\& 
2\left(\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right) +i\,\sin \left(\frac{5\pi}{6} \right)  \right),
\\& 
2\left(\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3} + \right) +i\,\sin \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)  \right),
\\& 
2\left(\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{6} \right) +i\,\sin \left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right)  \right)
\end{align*}
$$
That is, our solutions are
$$
z \in \{1 + i \sqrt 3, -\sqrt 3 + i, -1 - i\sqrt 3, \sqrt 3 - i\}
$$